# SQL CREATE FUNCTION generates 'no such function' error

Tags: sql

I am trying to generate a column which is not stored in the database. The column obtains its value from a function. The problem is there is an error of 'no such function:'
What should I do to get the value from this function and assign it to the column?
My SQL script so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETAVERAGE (@locationID AS INTEGER)
RETURNS NUMERIC
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @avg AS NUMERIC
SET @avg = SELECT AVG(value) FROM properties WHERE location_id = @locationID
END;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS properties
(
    property_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    location_id INTEGER,
    address VARCHAR (100),
    value NUMERIC,
    average_prop_value NUMERIC GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GETAVERAGE(location_id)) VIRTUAL,
    FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES locations (location_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS locations
(
    location_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE
);
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html  - seems you want more than generated columns can deliver.

Comment: So what do you recommend as an alternative?

Comment: I recommend to keep normalized data and calculate aggregate values on the fly.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how to do that. Let me research.

Comment: Probably this would be better implemented using a view.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which database you are using.  If you add a specific tag (and version detail) to the question, that could help.  It could be MySQL.  Here's standard SQL that would work with most databases (of a recent version):

```
SELECT t.*
     , AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY location_id) AS avg_value
  FROM properties t
;
```

Use this in a `VIEW`, if you wish.